# Can't view website on mobile from within same network as server

Tags: website, wireless-networking

I have a website running on a raspberryPi with apache through a static ip on the home router. I can access this website from everywhere through domainname or static ip without a problem.
But if I try to access it from within the same home router's network it doesn't work on mobile, while it works on desktop just fine.

I already searched online but didn't find anyone with the same problem.
I tried using the static ip instead of the domain but that didn't work either.

Maybe I have to use the local ip of the router but 192.168.1.1 just gets me to the router settings. I don't know where to configure the ip that apache uses for local access and couldn't find it on the internet either.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know where to configure the ip that Apache uses for local
>   access

This has nothing to do with Apache's configuration: it has whatever IP the RaspberryPi has on the *local area network*.

I assume the RaspberryPi is not used as the home router. Therefore, there must be a port forward through NAT i.e. `<publicIP>:80` gets forwarded to `<raspberryPiIP>:80`. The port forward only works from the WAN interface and the router's configuration site is on the LAN interface `192.168.1.1:80`.

So you need to know the IP of your RaspberryPi.

- You can find that from the router's configuration, where the port forward was set in the first place.
- You could use direct methods like pinging the broadcast address `192.168.1.255` and then checking ARP table with `arp -a`.
- Or use a tool like [Nirsoft FastResolver](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/fastresolver.html).

Comment: As I said I am using static ip. So the raspberry pi has the same address as the router. Meaning there is no internal ip for me to use on my phone rather than the actual domain/static ip address

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just looks like that because of the port forwarding. How come I know more of your home network than you so? :)

Comment: Ok, so if i somehow get that internal ip i can use it to view my website on mobile?

Comment: Probably yes. I have given 3 examples of how to do it.

Comment: But how do i do that on my phone?

Comment: Which flavor? iOS / Android / Windows Phone?

Comment: Device description  IP Address   MAC Address      Port Forwarding
NightmarPi 178.192.108.154
                fe80::dbf5:acf8:eafa:7d7d  00:e1:b0:10:1c:e1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59416/discussion-between-nightmare-and-esa-jokinen).

Comment: router configuration only shows me static ip. Pinging and arp -a does not reveal the ip either. Now trying Nirsoft.

Comment: Nirsoft fastresolver only found what I already saw in the router configuration. Meaning the raspberry pi did not appear at all but all of the other devices had their respective local ip.